# Python PyQt5 I wanna set the position of my Grid Layout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to set the position of my Grid Layout. It has to be exactly where I want it to be. I've tried some methods like ".setGeometry, .setAlignment" and I couldn't unfortunately have the result exactly I wanted. [image]

As you can see from this photo, I want it to be in the bottom right but I guess there's no method for it. (I need to say that the interface in the photo below is a different interface. I don't need this interface. Because of I wanted to show you exactly what kind of stuff I wanted.)

Comment: `setGeometry` will do what you are asking.  But it will fix the layout in one specific position.  So you would probably want to set the window to be a fixed size.

Comment: Are you trying to do that using Designer or by code? Will the final window always have that empty space in the middle?

Comment: @musicamante I'm trying to do it with using Qt Designer.

Comment: @Deezwend please answer all questions, and be more specific in explaining what you want to achieve, because by reading your comments on the current answer it seems like you're leaving out many important aspects, and you may even be asking the wrong question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using layouts and their `setStretch` methods.

Here is a runnable example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.central = QWidget()

        # create a vertical layout and add stretch so it is the first
        # item of the layout and everything that is inserted after
        # is pushed down to the bottom
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central)
        self.layout.addStretch()
       
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("PushButton", self)
        self.btn2 = QPushButton("PushButton", self)
        self.btn3 = QPushButton("PushButton", self)

        # create a horizontal layout and add stretch so everything is 
        # pushed to the right
        self.hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hlayout.addStretch()

        # add buttons after the stretch so they will be pushed to the 
        # right
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.hlayout.addWidget(self.btn3)

        # add horizontal layout to vertical layout which will be pushed
        # to the bottom from the vertical layouts stretch
        self.layout.addLayout(self.hlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central)

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

The alternative would be to use the `QHBoxLayout.setgeometry(QRect(x, y, w, h))` but this will force the layout into a specific position that will not adjust dynamically if you resize the window, or for any other reason.

This is essentially what is happening in the code above.  The blue lines would represent the `stretch`.  the stretch can be thought of as invisible pressure that can be inserted into any layout, before, after, or between any widgets, It can work in either direction.

This same process can be done using QGridWidget.

[image]

Comment: I tried this code and it's exactly I wanted but I couldn't understand exactly how addStretch() works. Is there any video about this?

Comment: @Deezwend  see image in my answer I just added .... the stretch is just invisible pressure that can be inserted into any layout, before, after, or between any widgets, It can work in either direction.

Comment: @Deezwend  I also added some notes to the code to better explain how it works....

Comment: So how can I make this compatible with each new button addition based on the number of information from the database? Do you know something about this?

Comment: @Deezwend  I have no idea what you mean.... Your question doesn't ask anything about a database